# Substitute backslash plus pipe in VI/Linus

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I have a pipe(|) separated file, but there some "\|" which messed up for further processing. 
How can I substitute "\|" into " |"(space pipe)?

I tried `:/\/|` in vi, it can find " \|" but I tried `%s//\//|/ //|/g` it is not working. Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vim, try:

```
%s/\\|/ |/g
```

it will change

```
aa\|bb|cc
```

into

```
aa |bb|cc
```

or using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\\|/ |/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can issue the following command:

```
:1,$s/\\|/ |/g
```